# why doesn't django update form repopulate my fields with existing data

Tags: django, django-forms

This is the template that should update existing model. I have looked through multiple tutorials but I still don't have a clue why my form's fields aren't prepopulated. Does anybody have any idea what's wrong?

My form:

```
class UpdateSiteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = ('name', 'description', 'URL',)
```

my model:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    URL = models.URLField(default=None)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None)
```

my template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="updatesite">
    <h2>{{site.name}} Update-page</h2> 
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Update</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

my views.py

```
def updatesite(request,id):
    site = get_object_or_404(Site, id=id)
    dev = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateSiteForm(request.POST,instance=site,initial=site)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('userhome')
    else:
        form = UpdateSiteForm()
    return render(request,'updatesite.html',{'site':site, 'form': form})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't passing the instance that it should get the form data from:

```
def updatesite(request,id):
    site = get_object_or_404(Site, id=id)
    dev = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateSiteForm(request.POST,instance=site,initial=site)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('userhome')
    else:
        form = UpdateSiteForm(instance=site)
    return render(request,'updatesite.html',{'site':site, 'form': form})
```